# Can't log in to Wifi router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I bought a wireless AP about a month ago. I've been running it fine since then with unsecured wifi. I used to be able to log in to it at 192.168.1.1 but now I just see a screen saying something about resetting the router. I wanted to log in to change the wireless channel because I noticed it started to get slow.

So I tried resetting the router but I still just see this screen and cannot log-in. Also the wifi no longer works.

Here is a screen shot of what i see at 192.168.1.1 and a translation (I'm in china).

http://imagebin.org/160683

Any idea what is going on here?

I did a hard reset just now and still I cannot get a login prompt, only that message in the screenshot. I've also confirmed that 100% the gateway is 192.168.1.1. It's on back of router and in ipconfig/all.

Is it possible that someone who connected to it might have uploaded a corrupt firmware? I've also had a lot of messages lately from my eset security package saying that there is DNS poisoning or something almost every time I visit a web page. I was stupid, leaving the default login of admin/admin but understand that the router's interface is in Chinese without any English, and I don't read chinese so changing the defaults is not as easy as you might think. It took me like an hour before just to setup PPoE.

I didn't secure the wifi because I like to share and I feel bad for neighbors here who don't have internet.

Comment: What is the default gateway?

Comment: 192.168.1.1  is the default

Comment: I haven't been able to log in for a few days, i need get back in so i can set up PPOE again else it's useless.

Comment: i would double check (ipconfig)

Comment: It's written on the back of the router, i'm certain it is correct.

Comment: @dt101 What brand/model is your router?

Answer (score 0):

How long did you press the reset button for? Most routers have a quick reset and a more thorough reset. What about just powering it off for 10 minutes?

Comment: i held the reset button for 3 minutes and also tried powering off.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing a hard reset, follow [these](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Hard_reset_or_30/30/30) instructions.